# has_secure_password, RSpec and user creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am trying to get a minimal test to pass with Rspec and user login. Part of that means setting up a user that uses authentication with has_secure_password. I am trying with this:

```
scenario 'test signin' do
  @attr = { :email => "jtjt@some.com",
             :password => "pass123"
  }
  User.create!(@attr)
  visit signin_path
  fill_in 'Email', with: 'jtjt@some.com'
  fill_in 'Password', with: 'pass123'
  click_button 'Log in'
end
```

I have added

```
attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation
```

but get the following error:

```
1) test login with email test signin
   Failure/Error: User.create!(@attr)
   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `password_digest=' for #<User:0x007fd89b02a028>
   # ./integration/email_login_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have tried adding :password_confirmation but actually get the same error (?). I will be using something like FactoryGirl but wanted to get this piece workign which I thought would be simple. Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

thx

**edit 2**
we do have the password_digest field and the code has been working for awhile. Just wanted to add some integration tests when I took project over.

Comment: Make also sure you have 'password_digest' in 'attr_accessor' in your user model

Comment: thx ted, I had tried with password_digest in attr_accessible and it didn't change things. I am able to login fine via web interface with password_digest not in attr_accessible. Also, password_digest would seem to be a bad idea in attr_accessible

Comment: sorry but once again, make sure you have 'password_digest' in '**attr_accessor**'(not just attr_accessible) in your user model

Comment: wow, thx ted, this seems to be it (sorry for numbskullery too). If you want to answer, feel free and I'll accept. I ended up using factory_girl too which has a different strategy than

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make also sure you have `password_digest` in [**attr_accessor**](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor) in your user model.